# jOOQ idempotent batch insert

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm trying to implement an idempotent insert, this query looks good for this task

```sql
insert into test_table
select *
from (
         values (1, 2, 3, 4),
                (3, 4, 5, 6),
                (1, 2, 3, 4),
                (3, 4, 5, 6)
     ) as data(a, b, c, d)
where not exists(select 1
                 from test_table
                 where test_table.a = data.a
                   and test_table.b = data.b
                   and test_table.c = data.c);
```

Please help translate this query to jOOQ DSL
I used Greenplum database and is not supported `ON CONFLICT` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
ctx.insertInto(TEST_TABLE)
   .select(
       select()
       .from(values(
           row(1, 2, 3, 4),
           row(3, 4, 5, 6),
           row(1, 2, 3, 4),
           row(3, 4, 5, 6)
       ).as("data", "a", "b", "c", "d"))
       .whereNotExists(
           selectOne()
           .from(TEST_TABLE)
           .where(TEST_TABLE.A.eq(field(name("data", "a"), TEST_TABLE.A.getDataType())))
           .and(TEST_TABLE.B.eq(field(name("data", "b"), TEST_TABLE.A.getDataType())))
           .and(TEST_TABLE.C.eq(field(name("data", "c"), TEST_TABLE.A.getDataType())))
       )
   )
   .execute();
```

This answer is assuming you're using the code generator for `TEST_DATA` (otherwise, construct your identifiers manually, as shown above for `name("data", "a")`, etc. [or as shown here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names/)). Also, it assumes:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

[When Greenplum is formally supported, see #4700](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4700), then `ON CONFLICT` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE` can be emulated for you.